# Laravel - Read an SQLite file dynamically

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to work on a project that accepts an SQLite file via upload, saves it, and parses the data in the SQLite database. I am finding that when I use a smaller DB file the "-wal" and "-shm" files are not being created but when using a larger DB (at least 2mb) they are.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$destination = storage_path().'/tempDir/databases/'.$userId.'/';

//store the file in the directory
$request->file('database')->move($destination .'database/database.db');

$destination = $destination.'database/database.db';
Config::set('database.connections.sqlite.database', $dbLocation);
$sqliteDbConnection = \DB::connection('sqlite');
$getUsers = $sqliteDbConnection->table("users")->get();
```

Whenever I try and do this, I am getting the following error:
    "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error (SQL: select * from \"users\")"

Does anyone have an idea why that might be? I can confirm that the file being saved to the server is in good standing, I am able to open it with other SQLite viewers.

UPDATE: Is it possible that the link between Homestead and my MAC is prohibiting the file from being accessed by Laravel?

UPDATE2: The problem is 100% located in the sharing mechanism between VirtualBox and the computer. I tried this via XAMPP and it works alright. WTF?

Comment: I would go for PDO instead of trying to pass database to laravel: `$db = new PDO('sqlite:' . $destination);`

Comment: Ok, then how would I access the information inside the DB?

Comment: Like so: http://pastebin.com/aFsAVvbp

Comment: Thanks. When I try to implement your example, the prepare() method is returning false. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Catch and check error: http://pastebin.com/8q8Azrh9

Comment: Ha! its giving me the same error as above just in array form. That doesn't help. Could there be a problem accessing the SQLite file which was saved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108390/discussion-between-ackerchez-and-giedrius-kirsys).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed to get a Builder instance with my custom PDO connection:

```
$pathname = '/absolute/path/to.sqlite';

$connection = new \Illuminate\Database\SQLiteConnection(new \PDO('sqlite:' . $pathname));

$builder = new \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder($connection);

$builder->newQuery()->from('my_table')->get()->all();
```